# Routing with parameter conflicts issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

MY route config :

```
routes.MapRoute(
"LastTwoRoute",
"thong-ke-ket-qua-xo-so-2-so-cuoi/{cityID}/{pnumbers}/{pdays}/{ponlySpecial}",
new { controller = "LastTwo", action = "Index", 
        cityID = "MB", 
        pnumbers = "",
        pdays = 1000,
        ponlySpecial = false
});
```

The controller :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string cityID, string pnumbers, int pdays, bool ponlySpecial)
    {

 [HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string cityID, string pnumbers, int pdays, bool ponlySpecial)
{

    LastTwoParameters lastTwoParameters = new LastTwoParameters();
    lastTwoParameters.listCities = Common.GetDropDownCitiesList();
    lastTwoParameters.Numbers = pnumbers; 
    lastTwoParameters.Days = pdays;
    lastTwoParameters.OnlySpecial = ponlySpecial; 
    lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = new List<getReport_LastTwo_Result>();

    if (TempData["Redirection"] != null || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pnumbers) )
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityID) && pdays > 0)
        {
            using (KQXS context = new KQXS())
            {
                lastTwoParameters.listLastTwoResult = context.getReport_LastTwo(cityID, pnumbers, pdays, ponlySpecial).ToList();
            }
        }

    }
    return View(lastTwoParameters);
}

[HttpPost]//Run action method on form submission
public ActionResult Index(List<Cities> c, string cityID, string numbers, int days, bool onlySpecial)
{
    TempData["Redirection"] = true;
    return RedirectToRoute("LastTwoRoute", new { 
            cityID = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityID) ? "MB" : cityID ),
            pnumbers = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numbers) ? string.Empty : numbers) , 
            pdays = (days == 0 ? 1000 : days), 
            ponlySpecial = onlySpecial});
}
```

When I frist access the controller :

and hit the submit button without entering/modifying any parameter, there are no errors :

but if I modify **the third or the fourth** parameter, I will have this error :

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

I debuged the code, and at the line `RedirectToRoute` in `HttpPost`, every parameters are about the same except the parameter that I modified. I can't think of a reason why is this error happening!

If I enter/modified **the second parameter** (the second text box counting from top to bottom), I have no errors either!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

P/s : If this is not clarify enough for you because of my poor English, I can provide a screen video which records how I get the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `pnumbers = ""` in your route but it's not marked as an optional field (and you wouldn't be able to have it as optional if it's in the middle with required fields around it).

Try defaulting it to `"0"` or something.

Another alternative is to move this option to the end of the required parameters and mark it as optional like:

```
pnumbers = UrlParameter.Optional
```

It's worth installing [route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) if you are having routing issues as it adds a nice interface at the bottom of the page which shows which routes will trigger and which wont. It's essential with complex routes IMO.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I still don't get it why the submit wihout entering/modifying any parameters doesn't generated any errors ?

Comment: Routing is an odd one regarding errors, I'd suggest going into Nuget and adding `Route Debugger` to your project. It produces a nice interface at the bottom of the page to show you which routes will match which won't which is very handy for complex routes. I'll update my post with this information

Comment: Oh, thanks for the suggestion! I'll get it right away! Thanks again! Best wishes!

Comment: Not a problem and glad I could help. Have fun :)